# How can I select rows in one table in a hierarchical form?

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchy

Let us suppose that I have 3 levels of users in my system, one for the `ordinary staffs`, the second one is for the `two supervisors` and the last one if for the `president` which is the highest. Supervisors are the approvers of ordinary staff whenever they are sending request on the system, while the president can approve requests of supervisors and ordinary staffs whenever they are sending request related to the company.

Suppose that I have a table `employee_information_tbl`, and the values for the column, `job_pos_status` are `5 = ordinary staff`, `6= supervisors` and `7 = president`.

`id                      name                  job_pos_status      approver_id`

`-----------------------------------------------------------------------------`

`001                   John Peter                     7                 001`

`002                   Anne Sy                        6                 001`

`003                   Abigail Sam                    6                 001`

`004                   Paul Top                       5                 002`

`005                   Lenny Bots                     5                 003`

`006                   Steve Max                      5                 002`

`007                   Max Collins                    5                 003`

`008                   Anne Dy                        5                 003`

`009                   Maine Mendoza                  5                 002`

Question:
How can I select all the records (that is accessible by the president) without using `all` query, but a logical one that follows the hierarchy of their organization?

Comment: Do not mix multiple questions in one question. Ask them separately, otherwise the answers may get mixed as well.

Comment: The point is how can I select query based on the hierarchy given? I just asked multiple question to point it out. :)

Comment: Nope, the 1st one is a simple query with an `or` condition in the where criteria or 2 simple ones combined with a union. The 2nd one is more complicated, especially if you a want a generic query applicable even if the levels increase.

Comment: Question is already edited, let's focus more on the second question.

Comment: Okay, i think we should focus more on the second question, but it has the same idea actually.

Answer (score 0):

```
You want the query based on hierarchy, please check this :


create table employee_information_tbl (id nvarchar(3), name nvarchar(50), job_pos_status int, approver_id nvarchar(3) )

insert into employee_information_tbl
select '001', 'John Peter', 7, '001'
union all
select '002', 'Anne Sy', 6, '001'
union all
select '003', 'Abigail Sam', 6, '001'
union all
select '004', 'Paul Top', 5, '002'
union all
select '005', 'Lenny Bots', 5, '003'
union all
select '006', 'Steve Max', 5, '002'
union all
select '007', 'Max Collins', 5, '003'
union all
select '008',' Anne Dy', 5, '003'
union all
select '009', 'Maine Mendoza', 5, '002'

select  a.id, a.name, 
        a.job_pos_status, 
        a.approver_id,
        a.approver_id 
from    employee_information_tbl a 
        Inner join  (select distinct job_pos_status 
                    from employee_information_tbl 
                    ) b
        on b.job_pos_status = a.job_pos_status
order by b.job_pos_status desc, 
         a.approver_id, 
         a.id

drop table employee_information_tbl
```